# If I ask a question and it gets a lot of down votes, should I delete it or leave it up?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, best-practices

If I have 3 downvotes on a post should I delete it or should I edit it? What should I do?

Comment: Edit it to improve it.  Don't delete it.  For more details about how you can improve the question, see [How to ask a good question on Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+to+ask+a+good+question)

Comment: The main reason you should try to save the question is because having deleted and/or net downvoted questions (much worse if both) contributes to an eventual question ban.

Comment: Thank you guys it was very helpful!

Comment: There is the Peer Pressure badge to be earned if you want one.

Comment: Indeed, @MattSamuel.  You did a good job of explaining why I posted the comment I posted.